# Go down the hall meaning? (For giving directions)

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrases

When I asked for the directions to the HR's cubicle, I got this reply:

> Go down the hall then take the first left, You will find the HR's cubicle there.

(I don't remember exactly what he said.)

I am assuming by down the hall he meant to go straight and then take a left.

Can I apply the same logic for streets and roads while giving the directions?

Go down the road and then take a left.

I would really appreciate if someone can explain the meaning of the phrase "down the hall" in this context.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're implying by "he meant *to go straight **into** the hall.*" The speaker is using *exactly* the same construction as he would if you were outside, and he was talking about *going down the **road*** or ***street*** rather than ***hall.*** And although we wouldn't often say it anyway, *Go [straight] **into** the street* doesn't mean the same thing as *Go [straight] **down** the street*.

Comment: Note that ***up / down*** in such contexts doesn't necessarily have anything to do with any change in elevation, and unless the road / street / hallway floor is *exceptionally* steeply inclined, different speakers will often almost randomly choose between those two prepositions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers what exactly does that phrase mean "down the road". Does "Go down the road" mean "Go straight"? and is it common phrase?

Comment: Often it's just a matter of saying that the structure of *to go **up / down / along** the [road / street / path / etc].* requires a ***preposition*** in the highlighted position. Other than that, it doesn't necessarily "mean" much at all. But note that it's never *syntactically* necessary to include the word ***straight*** - that just adds a kind of "emphasis" (***immediately*** and/or ***without deviating***).

Answer (score 1):

***Down the hall*** just means *along the hall*. Sometimes, a speaker will have in their own mind which way is *down* and which way is *up*, and sometimes they'll just use *down* or *up* randomly, arbitrarily, or always using the same one regardless of direction.

Me, I tend to think of *down* a hallway as being the direction away from the entrance or main hall or similar, going "down into the depths" of a building, and *up* is back towards the central areas of the building. I have no idea how many people think like that.

Comment: FWIW, my wife says that to her, "up" is towards the nearest 'end' of the hallway or corridor, and "down" is away from it. As long as there's an end pretty close, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

People giving road directions routinely say 'take a left or right' to indicate a deviation into another road or street.

> take a left
>   (also hang a left American English)
>   to turn left
>   Take the next left (=turn left at the next road).
>
> [Take a left (Longmans)](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/take-a-left)

Comment: Perhaps I'm suffering from false memory, but it seems to me I can clearly recall navigators / passengers telling me to ***Hang a left / right here!*** before 1970 here in SE UK. But the first cite in OED (1967) is actually only "indirect" anyway: * Evening Standard 26 July 13/3   If you're in your pig [sc. car, in Detroit] and you ‘hang a Louie’, you've just turned left. If you ‘hang a Ralph’, it's a right turn, ‘hang a Sam’ is go straight and ‘hang a Ulysses’ means make a U-turn* (their first "real" one is a 1975 CB slang dictionary). But they do say *colloq. (**orig. and chiefly** U.S.)*

Comment: Living in Dulwich, SE London, (not the posh part) I certainly heard it in American films & TV shows before around 1975. Transpondial osmosis being what it is, it's pretty likely it was used in Britain around then.

Comment: Yeah, well I suppose I was a "slightly rebellious" adolescent back in the late 60s, which probably meant me & my peers were a bit inclined to grab some of our "alternative / subversive" vocabulary from America (anything to seperate ourselves off from our parent's generation). As I recall, we used to call a half-crown coin (2s 6d) a half-dollar (which even back then was stretching the exchange rate to breaking point and beyond! :)

Comment: Half a dollar for half a crown was Cockney/street slang way before the 60s. From the 1930s to the early 1960s, a US dollar was worth around 5 shillings; hence the rhyming slang "Oxford (scholar)" for that sum.

Comment: Ty - I didn't know that. Many people would say I'm a Cockney myself, even though I've never actually *lived* in London at all - let alone within earshot of Bow Bells. But I swear even today I still learn the original Cockney rhyme for some familiar turn of phrase thing several times a month. Mainly from a globe-trotting friend who really ***is*** a dyed-in-the-wool Cockney. As you can imagine, facing constant blank looks from people he talks to abroad *and* having a smartphone, he's got into the habit of Googling the origin for anything he doesn't already know (and telling *me* later).

Comment: (But I have to say ***You stupid berk**!* still creases me up sometimes; I'm a bit coarse-spoken at the best of times, but since discovering that one some 30 years ago I've often felt conflicted over my not-infrequent failure to avoid it in polite and/or female-inclusive company! :)

Comment: This does not answer the question which is to explain the meaning of, "down the hall"

Comment: @chasly The question was rather less clear when this answer was written.

Comment: I did down-vote. However I didn't notice when this was answered or who answered it (I'm just not that observant).  I didn't go back in history to follow you. The question floated to the top because SamBC posted a new answer. He has now pointed out that the question has since changed. My vote is locked in now so I can't do anything about it.  P.S. I wondered why all the comments seemed unrelated to the question. Who changed the question anyway?