# exact meaning of "down the street"

Tags: meaning

How to interpret the meaning when someone tells me that a particular building is down the street? Is it at the end of the road, middle or at the opening?

Comment: It’s further, along that street

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83597/up-my-street-and-down-the-lane

Comment: Also relevant (principle may be similar): https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/180565/go-down-the-hall-meaning-for-giving-directions

Comment: Like many phrases in English (and probably other languages), it doesn't have an **exact** meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will hear "up the street" as well as "down the street". Both essentially mean "*along* the street", and are generally from the perspective of the speaker - that is whether they consider the direction to be "up" or "down". It does not refer to a specific location *on* the street such as the end or half-way along, but to a direction away from where you already are. If we mean to indicate that something is right at the end we will say so, using either "at the bottom of the street" or "at the end of the street".

In British English, we tend to use "up" and "down" when speaking about travelling from one part of the country to another - "up" when travelling broadly in a northerly direction, and "down" when travelling southwards, for example:

> I'm going down to London.
>
> I'm going up to Glasgow.

When it comes to talking about travelling along a  *street* I doubt very much whether many people give much thought to which compass direction they are facing, so in answering this question I did look to see how often "up the street" is used versus "down the street", and as [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=up%20the%20street%2Cdown%20the%20street&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cup%20the%20street%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdown%20the%20street%3B%2Cc0) shows, "down the street" is used far more. I would suggest that the reason for this is, unlike when compass direction is an influencing factor, "down the street" far better describes travelling *away* from a fixed point from the perspective of someone giving directions.

As an aside, the expression "up *my* street" is a saying used idiomatically to mean that something is familiar or well-suited to a person, or in their field of expertise, which may explain why [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=up%20my%20street%2Cdown%20my%20street&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cup%20my%20street%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdown%20my%20street%3B%2Cc0) shows it can be used more than the equivalent expression that uses "down".

Comment: As thoroughly explored in another question recently, up and down are often about the destination as much as the direction. London is "up" from anywhere in the south-east, and to many people from anywhere in the country.

Comment: @SamBC You say that destination determines which word to use - so are you saying that everybody in England, no matter their location, says "I'm going down to London"? Because that is not true. People here are very quick to correct you if you use the wrong direction. If you live South of a place you are travelling to, you would use "up", else face correction.

Comment: Across the south-east, London is "up". Essex, Kent, Sussex, Hertfordshire, all of them say "up" to get to London, in my experience. The further you get from London, the less likely people are to cal it "up" even if it's south of you. The dictionary also covers that sense of 'up' as well. Sense 4 at https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/up

Comment: @SamBC Wow, I wonder which country I've been living in for the past 40 years then? It can't be England because your dictionary says not. Anyway, my point in this answer was to *contrast* that, because I don't believe compass directions have much to do with whether someone refers to travelling up or down a street.

Comment: I don't know, maybe there's a class-cultural or regional component. I was just mentioning it so readers know there's another side to your absolutist assertion. I grew up in the south-east of England, so I'm pretty familiar with that usage there. Also, Oxford wouldn't include it if they weren't confident in it being well-attested.

Comment: Although *down the street* is an idiom according to [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/down+the+Street) and means: 
*a short distance away on this same street. Sally lives just down the street. There is a drugstore down the street.*, I wonder if the street is on a hill and if talking about something that is further uphill would we still say *down the street?*. Perhaps we would say *up the street?*.

Comment: @SamBC If you look at a map of UK, note where London is, and then consider just what a small percentage of the country's landmass everything south of that is, I definitely think we should take into consideration what the rest of the country says. Also, consider that people who live in London mostly get by using the underground map which has no bearing on actual geography or compass directions, so it should not be surprising they don't know which direction they are travelling in.

Comment: @LucianSava Absolutely, if the street were on an incline then this would have a bearing on choice of word. I don't agree that it always means a short distance though... in isolation it could mean literally any distance, but we might specify "all the way down the street", or "half a mile down the street".

Comment: @Astralbee: Kent and Essex are largely not on the underground, nor is Sussex or Herts. And none of Essex is south of London, nor Herts. We take into consideration what the rest of the country says, and north/south definitely influence up/down language, but it's not an automatic north->up, down->south. There are other factors involved. It's not common, but it's not weird for someone here in north Lancashire to refer to Manchester as "up", either.

Comment: @SamBC As someone living in North Lancashire (Blackpool) I would expect to hear someone say they had "*come over*" or "come *across*" from Manchester. I would never say I'm going "up" there. But again, this is way off topic for this question. I didn't bring "across" into it because "across the street" means something entirely different.